Config export annoation not working
I have a config entity with the following config_export annotation.
 *   config_export = {
 *     "id",
 *     "label",
 *     "is_staging"
 *   },

The config entity also has some other fields like access_token that I want to save but not export. When I do a config export it exports all the fields not just the ones in the config_export array.
Is this how it's supposed to work.
